# a comparison equals to true, but when i put it as if condition, why it is not evaluated as true?

Tags: go

```
a := "ALL"
b := "not all"

if (a == "ALL") != (b == "ALL") {
    fmt.Printf("why not falling into this case?\n")
}
```

Here is a piece of Go code I wrote, to print something if a and b have exactly one to be "ALL". But why the fmt.Printf is not triggered?

However the following does print:

```
c := (a == "ALL") != (b == "ALL")
if c {
    fmt.Printf("if assign to c, do fall in here\n")
}
```

But what's the difference between the two pieces?

I also pasted the above code in the go playground: http://play.golang.org/p/e5tNai_d20 Anyone's explanation will be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you not just compare a to b?

Comment: This works: `if ((a == "ALL") != (b == "ALL")) == true {`. This is strange, I see nothing in the spec explaining this.

Comment: i want to treat all non-ALL string as the same. e.g. print nothing if a=="some string", b=="some other string"

Comment: The second form can be reduced to `if c:=(a == "ALL") != (b == "ALL"); c {`

Comment: Oh duh that makes sense. It's late.

Comment: the thing I have no idea is, since (a == "ALL") != (b == "ALL") is true, why not falling to the if case? just don't know why the first piece does not work

Comment: An observation: it works as expected for integers.

Comment: Another observation, it works when if (a == "ALL") == (b == "ALL")  you compare for equality. It's definitely the bug, because it doesn't work as people expect.

Comment: I just asked the golang-nuts mailing list. We'll see.

Comment: @DenysSéguret please post link to your question here

Comment: @VladMiller I don't see my question, it might be quarantined. I just tested on my computer, I don't have the problem (go1.4.2 linux/amd64)

Comment: Fixed in go 1.5.1. Voting to close this question.

Answer (score 7):

It is a go 1.5 bug, and looks similiar to this one : https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12226

It is fixed on the master branch, so you can either downgrade to 1.4.2 and wait for the next release, or compile the tip of master.

Edit : Go1.5.1 has been released and it contains the fix to this issue